# Associated extension doesn't send file name to application on double click

Tags: c#, clickonce, args, file-association

I have specified a file extension to be associated with my program (Window Application) through **Project Properties >> Publish >> Options >> File Associations** in Visual Studio 2013.

I know that if I drag one or several files and drop it on my application (*.exe*), I can catch all the paths through the arguments (*string[] args*) of my Main method (*located in Program.cs*). But when I open an associated file (*which launches my published and installed application*), the path of the file is not passed as an argument to my Main method.

How can I catch the path of the file(s) which has launched my application?

BTW, I can also use registry (*HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*) to associate file extensions with my application beside using Visual Studio's "File Associations" feature. Which method do you recommend the most and why?

Comment: So, you're saying that if you double-click a data file in Windows Explorer and that file type is registered with your app so it opens your app, you don't get the data file path via the `args` parameter of your `Main` method, right?  That sounds odd.  What if you call `Environment.GetCommandlineArgs`?

Comment: The Registry is the only way to associate a file type with your app.  Any installation tool will simply do that for you.  If you're using ClickOnce to deploy your app then you should absolutely use the file association functionality built into ClickOnce.  It is completely transparent to the user and that's always a good thing.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I tried Environment.GetCommandlineArgs() but the only difference it made was to return the path of the .exe file itself (alongside the dragged and dropped files). And BTW, I am using ClickOnce an its file association functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved my own problem with the following code:

```
        RegistryKey command, defaultIcon, extension;
        // Create Keys
        command = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Classes\APP NAME\shell\open\command");
        defaultIcon = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Classes\APP NAME\DefaultIcon");
        extension = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Classes\.EXTENSION");

        // Create Values
        command.SetValue("", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\" %1", RegistryValueKind.String);
        defaultIcon.SetValue("", "ICON PATH", RegistryValueKind.String);
        extension.SetValue("", "APP NAME", RegistryValueKind.String);
```

**APP NAME** is where I put the name of my application,
**EXTENSION** is where I put the extension I want to associate with my application, and **ICON PATH** is the path to the icon file which I want the associated files to have.

The **%1** at the end of the ExecutablePath makes the path of the double-clicked associated file to be passed as an argument to Main method of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Check the registry editor:

- [Win+R], type "regedit"
- Open HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
- Open the .yourfileextension key
- In the key where your path of the executable is stored check if there's an `%%1`
- if not rightclick and Edit it like this: `"C:\Path\to\Executable\executable.exe" %%1`

Comment: Thanks, I know this would work where there is a value which holds the full path to the target of the association. But here's the weird thing, there are several values under the key, but none of them represent a full path, they only hold AppID and some other stuff!

Comment: Then create your own file association with the above shown key in C# or with vbs